# Xcode 14.3.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode14.3

Getting this error while archive ios app

**Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

I tried all solution on internet

How do I resolve "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" error when trying to archive project.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution working for me:

Step 1: Open xcode and search for the following line

source="$(readlink "${source}")"
The file directory would be : ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh

Step 2: Replace the searched line in the code with -f

Before

source="$(readlink "${source}")"
Change this to:

source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your node path is right

check file

```
.xcode.env.local
```

if this file is not existing in you ios folder so create file and
write

```
export NODE_BINARY="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@20/20.11.0/bin/node"
```

write you node path and [image]